# Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. Flask

Tags: python, flask

> I am trying to pass a row value of table for displaying in a new
> route if a user wants to see all full details of that row in a new page. row is a dictionary which I want to pass.this is one of many tds in a table created in maintable.html page

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ url_for('details' , row = row )}}" class="btn btn-info""> View</a>
</td>
```

> the route which I created and declared in my **init**.py is as follow :

```
    @app.route("/details/<row>")
    def details(row):
        return render_template("details.html", row = row )
```

> this is my details.html page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  some other codes
</head>
<body> 

<div class="container">
  <div class="well">Website</div>
  <p class="lead">
    {{row.website}}
  </p>
  
  <div class="well">Title</div>
  <p class="lead">
    {{row.title}}
  </p>

  <div class="well">Organization</div>
  <p class="lead">
    {{ row.organization }}
  </p>

  <div class="well">Description</div>
  <p class="lead">
    {{ row.description }}
  </p>

  <div class="well">Close Date</div> 
  <p class="lead">
    {{ row.close_date }}
  </p>

  <div class="well">Downlaods</div> 
  <p class="lead">
    {{ row.close_date }}
    {% for link in row.downloads %}
      {% if link != '' %}
      <a href="{{ link }}">[{{ loop.index }}]</a>
    {% else %} 
      <p>N/A</p>     
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
  
  </p>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> when I click on the view button it gives me error as:
> **Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
> entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.**

can anybody help me with if my code is correct for passing the row and how to fix the error.
your help is much appreciated since I am trying to learn Flask

Comment: do you passed the value of row in maintable.html?

Comment: And please share your init.py completely.I want to see your main route.

Comment: rows is a list of dictionary passed along with route "/home" after getting from SQL database. this route is rendering a template having a table(maintable.html). each table row is showing some data of each dict present in the rows list. now I created a button for each table row to display full contents of that row in separate route if he wants to see.